# Pass a jQuery variable into a PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery, variables

I'm working in PHP and I added the following jQuery code to display the current year:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/script/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#year").text( (new Date).getFullYear() );
  });
</script>

<p><span id="year"/></p>
```

(this code works perfectly: when displaying the page I can see 2015)

What I now want is to put this current year into a PHP variable (like $currentYear), so I will be able to use it in PHP for operations like this one:

```
$purchaseYear = 1985;
$yearsLivedOld = $currentYear-$purchaseYear;
```

How to put the year in a PHP variable ?

Comment: Use AJAX to pass that in your server side.

Comment: You seem pretty confused what happens clientside and serverside. You DON'T put a javascript variable into a PHP variable. You can of course post the value of the variable to PHP (using XHR or something like that, a form, an url, etc.). Be aware that the PHP code that produced your page ended when your clientside javascript starts.

Comment: only Ajax can do this

Comment: Or you just use `$foo = date('Y');` in PHP to get the current year. No need for JavaScript at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in the way you're trying to do it. Javascript (and thus JQuery) work on the client machine, after the page was sent and the connection with server closed. To get data from client machine your best bet would be an AJAX call which opens a new connection to the server and allows you to load (and send) additional data between the client and the server.

Whole AJAX tutorial is out of scope here, but [maybe this link will help you](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php).

If you only want the current year though, you can skip the javascript and do it in PHP, like so:

```
$purchaseYear = date("Y");
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP is rendered server side and javascript is rendered client side.
So in a way you can say that PHP is rendered before javascript, which means that you can assign a PHP variable to a javascript variable but cannot do vice-versa.
Therefore you can choose either of the solutions provided by aldrin27 or Till Helge.
Either use
1. AJAX to pass the data generated by javascript to server so that PHP can render it.
2. You can directly get current date in PHP using date('Y'); so there is no need of javascript for this piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ajax to pass the variable to your php script

```
var year = $("#year").text();
$.post("your_script.php", {year: year});
```

and after that you can use the variable in your php script

```
<?php
$year = $_POST['year'];
echo $year;
?>
```

you can learn more about ajax in [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/what_is_ajax.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jQuery AJAX function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (or the [post shorthand function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)).

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'path/to/myscript.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: 'current_year=' + currentYear,
  success: function(data) {
    //Optional callback function on success
  }
});
```

PHP:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  if (isset($_POST['current_year'])) {
    //Should really validate/sanitise data here
    $currentYear = $_POST['current_year'];
  }
}
```

You could also send it via an HTML post, although that would require a page reload, so AJAX would be more preferable.